# Is nesting View Models in MVVM considered an acceptable architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, blazor, viewmodel

I've been reading on MVVM architecture for blazor-server lately. I see certain advantages, however no matter how I scaffold my code I end up with the same question notion that my View Model is not how it is supposed to look in MVVM concept.

The View of the app I am developing is rather vast. It contains multiple components most of which are dependent on global states (i.e. bool SelectionInProgress, int SelectedCellId, bool ShowOptions, bool ReadyForSomething etc). There are around 20 such properties plus dozens of pure business properties and methods which does the business logic. All of this spaghetti is thrown into a single View Model which I believe is not a valid solution.

Separating single View Model into several View Models seems a reasonable solution, however it creates a need of complicated communication between View Models which creates more spaghetti, hence turning out to be fighting fire with fire.

My question is: Is it a good and common practice to create nested View Models? What I mean is creating "specialized" View Models for each component (or partial View) and then making an instance of each of them inside a single parent/global ViewModel that is injected through Interface into the View?

```
public class Child_ViewModel_1
{
   Property_1;
   ...
   Property_n;

   Method_1()
   ...
   Method_m()
}
```

```
public class Child_ViewModel_2
{
   Property_1;
   ...
   Property_r;

   Method_1()
   ...
   Method_t()
}
```

```
public class Parent_ViewModel
{
   Child_ViewModel_1 //Instance of child ViewModel_1
   Child_ViewModel_2 //Instance of child ViewModel_2

   Global_Property_1;
   ...
   Global_Property_x;

   Global_Method_1()
   ...
   Global_Method_y()
}
```

```
public interface IParent_ViewModel
{
   Child_ViewModel_1
   Child_ViewModel_2

   Global_Property_1; 
   ...
   Global_Property_p;

   Global_Method_1() 
   ...
   Global_Method_k()
}
```

And then injecting interface into the View component/page/whatever:

```
@inject IParent_ViewModel IParent_VM
```

I've read different opinions on where should the BL be. Most say it should be placed in Model, some say part of it may be in View Model, some suggest additional service layer between Model and View Model. Nevertheless, all this data have to communicate with each other and I suspect a ViewModel is a place of binding everything together and making it available to the View.

Please correct me if such architecture is not a good idea. I've become short of ideas and as of now the more I read the more I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think this statement is telling:

> Separating single View Model into several View Models seems a reasonable solution, however it creates a need of complicated communication between View Models which creates more spaghetti, hence turning out to be fighting fire with fire.

If the model you are applying results in "spaghetti" then there's something amiss!

My personal approach is to separate out the data state from the component state.  The view contains the data and a state object that represents the component state.  The state object can then be persisted across page cycles.  To illustrate, the current data set - `IEnumerable<TRecord>` Records - is held by the `RecordViewService` while the Page No and Page Size is held in a `ListState` object within the view.